# Envió de datos por data-target

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap, base-de-datos

¿como puedo enviar datos a través de data-target?

```
<?php

    while ($muestra = mysqli_fetch_array($busqueda)) {
        echo '<tr>';

        echo '<td >' . $muestra['id_persona'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td >' . $muestra['nombre'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td >' . $muestra['nombre_muni'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td >' . $muestra['nombre_depa'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>
                  <a class="btn btn-danger ajax-request" id="eliminar"  data-target="'.$muestra['id_persona'].'"> *en esta parte trato de capturar los datos pero no se en si como hacerlo investigue pero no encuentro algo funcional*
                  <i   class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                  </a>

                 </td>';
        echo ' </tr>';

    }
    ?>




<?php

//$busca="";

$busca=$_REQUEST['id'];

$mysqli=new MySQLI("localhost","root","","persona_municipio");
if ($mysqli-> connect_errno) {
    die("Fallo la conexion a MySQLI:(".$mysqli->mysqli_connect_errno()
        .")".$mysqli->mysqli_connect_error());

}
if ($busca!="") {
    $busqueda=mysqli_query($mysqli,"delete  from persona where id_persona = '".$busca."'");

    echo "Se Borro Exitosamente";
}
else {
    echo "error al borrar";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacerlo con Javascript y partir el código que tienes actualmente.
Todo tu PHP debes ponerlo en un archivo a parte ( El PHP que elimina las personas ) y esa ruta donde esté el archivo pasarla al AJAX. Te dejo el ejemplo comentado

```
//Función cuando el DOM esté listo
$(function(){
  //Capturar el evento cuando le den click al botón con clase ajax-request
  $(document).on('click','.ajax-request',function(){
    //Este selector tiene el ID del data-target lo sacamos
    var target = $(this).data('target');

    //Abrimos una conexión ajax y enviamos el valor, se llamará id, esto para que lo puedas recoger en el back
    $.ajax({
      url: 'path_al_backend.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data:{id:target},
      success:function( respuesta ){
        alert( respuesta )
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono tal y como me lo indicaste

Comment: Si te sirvió, recuerda marcar como correcta la respuesta.